# Disable Angular's Dragging Animation

Tags: angular, animation, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for away to disable Angular's animation when dragging elements. Currently Angular smoothly drag the element, if you move the mouse quickly the dragged element will follow the mouse smoothly not instantly. This isn't the behaviour I want. Is there a way to disable the animation or change it to instant move?

See below for a sample code

```
<div cdkDrag>Move Me</div>
```

Comment: Can you try to add these css:
`
.cdk-drag {
    transition: none;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: none;
}
`

Comment: So obvious and so simple, you are absolutely correct. Thank you, please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add these css:

```
.cdk-drag {
  transition: none;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: none;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, however would have been nice if Angular provided an input to disable it on demand